# How to cancel DbSet.Add in EF5

Tags: entity-framework

All, Say you have some code like below. I want to know If It didn't run the `db.savechanges()`, Is it necessary to write some code to Cancel `db.DeployPackages.Add(package)` commonly?

```
HotDeployDbContext db = null;

    using (db = new HotDeployDbContext())
    {
        DeployPackage package = new DeployPackage();
        db.DeployPackages.Add(package);

        //determine if save package to db based on some condition.
        if (.....)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            //how to cancel the db.DeployPackages.Add(package);
        }
    }
```

**Edited**

Sometimes we do lot of things in one `Dbcontext`, like add data to multiple table. delete some data or update data . but what if we do need to cancel these before run `SaveChanges` based on some business condition? How can I make this .Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the code exits the using block, all data will be thrown away and not saved.

Microsoft's official stance is that if you want to back out changes, you throw away the DbContext.  There is no good way to remove objects.

Comment: you mean `throw away` .Is that means it is better not use it again? thanks

Comment: @Joe.wang - No, I mean dispose.  new up a new one.

Comment: Right, that means close the db connection , So commonly put the code in a `Using` block.

Comment: @Joe.wang - no, it doesn't.  Connections are pooled by ado.net, so destroying the context does not close the connection, unless the connection has been idle for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

No.
As long as you don't call `SaveChanges()`, all of your changes only affect that `DbContext` instance.